# I need help to add my second effect after the first effect is over in letterFx jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

I am total new in jQuery. Very first time using any plugin for this purpose. I could manage it to make run after one effect. But I am total lost when I am trying add another effect in letterFX.

While Im trying for letterFX

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#name").letterfx({
                "fx":"fly-top"
                });
```

I am done with "fly-top" now I need to add another effect, you can say, any effect that is available in that plugin to add next, just when "fly-top" is finished. I could not add it anyway.

I want to add a link here. [TuxSudo](http://tuxsudo.com/code/project/letterfx#lfx_extending), its the site, I want to use this plug-in. But problem is, I'm not being able to use that callback function anyway, as I said earlier, I'm total new to jQuery.

Comment: sorry about that <pre>, if it makes you confused anyway. I just got puzzled while formatting it. :-/

Comment: have you looked at the onElementComplete option?

Comment: yes, I did. In fact, you are right, I am trying for that callback function.

Answer (score 1):

I dont quite get what you try to achieve but maybe you are looking for the callback function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#name").letterfx({
    "fx":"fly-top",
    "onElementComplete": function($element, LetterFXObj) {
      $("#name").letterfx({
        "fx":"smear",
        "onElementComplete": function($element, LetterFXObj) {
          alert("second fx done!");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: your alert did work. But fact is, I don't need that alert I need that "smear" to trigger on "#name" just after "fly-top" effect is done with it.

Comment: so then remove the alert?!

Comment: I need that "smear" effect in callback function for "#name" after "fly-top" effect is done with it.